# Implementing SignalR on my React App

Tags: c#, reactjs, signalr

I have read various tutorials and watched videos , I tried all of them and nothing seems to work.

My suspicion is this

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js</script> 
<script src = "/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script> 
<!-- <script src="http://localhost:9092/signalr/hubs"></script> --> 
 <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

the line of code:

```
 <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

causes this error :

```
hubs:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I have tried using this as a substitute:

```
 <script src="http://localhost:9092/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

But the problem is that it cannot see my hub. Based from the tutorials they say that I must be able to navigate to :

```
/signalr/hubs or /signalr/signalr/hubs
```

but both throws me to an error page of 404 by the way here is the code on my server :

Startup.cs

```
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            var hb = new HubConfiguration()
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hb);
        });
        app.MapSignalR();
```

And trying to access it on my component :

```
    componentDidMount() {

    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    // var hubConnection = connection.createHubProxy('Chat');

    connection.url = '~/signalr';
    connection.start({})
    .done(function (a) {
        console.log('================',a)
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
        console.log(connection);
        console.log(connection.chatHub);
        //$.connection.chat.server.tachChatHub();
        connection.chatHub.server.tachChatHub();
    })
    .fail(function (e) { console.error('Could not connect ' + e); });
}
```

It says that connection is established , and gives me a connection id. But when I am logging connection.chatHub , it says undefined thus i cannot trigger the function inside...

here is the code for the hub:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void TachChatHub(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Any Thoughts about this? I can't make it work...

EDIT:

After Tons of research , I had found out that after runnign the signalR should make a folder named "signalr" yet , it doesn't make on mine. Maybe I am Missing something here...

Comment: Try to open http://localhost:9092/signalr/negotiate from your browser and see if it shows a JSON

Comment: On js you call the methods like this:

`var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('Chat');
proxy.invoke('TachChatHub', {name:'something here',message:'something else here'});`

Comment: I tried doing this  :

 hubConnection.invoke('TachChatHub',{name:'something here',message:'something else here'});
        })

and set a breakpoint on the backend , it doesnt get triggered :'(

Comment: I tried doing locahost:9092/signalr/negotiate , it throws 404 =(

Comment: It means your server doesn't start

Comment: you should check for exceptions or use CurrPorts to check if the port actually opens

Comment: So the problem is on the server? I can’t seem to find the problem...

Comment: Are your `signalr` server and `js` app on the same domain?

Comment: no albert they are not

Comment: @xSkrappy Yes the problem is with the server, because it should at least answer on that url that throws 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue regarding Negotiate Made the connection start Like this :

```
   $.connection.hub.start({withCredentials:false})  
    .done(() => {
        console.log('Connected')
    })
    .fail((e) => { 
        console.log('Could not connect ' + e); 
    });
```

Apparently my previous cors setup is blocking it thus i need not to pass in credential to the server for the CORS Setup be hooked to the previous setup.

now Everything is working as what I Expected :)